# Prestashop mysql export old data

Tags: mysql, export, prestashop

I've made some updates to my prestashop product descriptions, but when I export data, it exports without my updates. 
How can I update prestashop DB to make an export with new informations?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, when you make an update, make sure the database reflects the new value of your product description.